# After php validation of user login, how do I record and use that information in Angular?

Tags: angular, session-state

After watching and reading tons of conflicting tutorials about login and registration, I have a working system that creates users or logs them in after verifying their details. It returns a userID to the front end which I store in my api service (the one that makes all the calls to php backend).

I'm storing the logged in user in PHP session variables to make sure only the right user is performing actions, but I would also like to keep track of the logged in user on the frontend. The problem is that every time the page reloads, the api service loses the data about the logged in user.

Here's what my login call looks like from a login component ts file:

```
    var response: any = this.api.loginUser(email, password).subscribe(res => {
  this.spinner.spinnerOff();
  console.log(res);
  if (res.success) {
    this.api.setUser(res.success);
    this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
  } else this.formError = true;
});
```

This works fine and I can use the value of api.userID (which is returned in res.success) to alter the "login/register" menu to say "welcome!" instead, but on page refresh, it's gone. Not only that, but I would think I need to do a new check on each route to make sure whether they're logged in anyway.

Do I need to send back logged in user data on every component load or is there some other way to manage user sessions? More importantly, how can that be done in a secure way? I would have to be backend-driven wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is done usually with your case is:

1. On login you send back in the response a JWT token (more info: https://jwt.io/)
2. You store that token in the `localStorage`
3. You create an interceptor which adds that token to the headers of every call which has to be protected (more info for example here: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8 or just just google "angular auth token interceptor"
4. If token is ok you do whatever you need. If not, you return 401 in the response and do stuff which needs to be done (usually remove the token from the `localStorage` and redirect the user to the login page).

Also you can add a `refreshToken` to have ability to add shorter lifespan to the `accessToken` and not forcing users to login every time it expires.

Comment: If I'm using PHP, why couldn't I just store the session in session variables and not use any front-end validation at all?

Comment: Because apps built with Angular consume some RESTful API (a PHP app in your case) and it cannot have any state. Back-end should not know anything about any specific front-end which consumes that back-end.

Comment: Ok, I've upvoted your answer and will check it out. I did see that infromation, but wasn't sure it was strictly necessary. I'll try again and vote if this ends up being the best answer.

Comment: Ok, the rabbithole never seems to end, but this breakdown helped a lot for me to get through this. I wasn't able to find a JWT library I could understand or a tutorial that lists both the creation and validation steps, but I've faked it for now. At the least, I understand the concept and can slot in proper JWT validation later.

Answer (score 2):

The browser gives you the possibility to store you data in local Storage and this data still persistent even if you reload the page

this link explain how to use local Storage:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can save user token in browser local storage

```
localStorage.getItem('__t');
localStorage.removeItem('__t');
localStorage.setItem('__t', session.object.token);
```

> Do I need to send back logged in user data on every component load or is there some other way to manage user sessions? More importantly, how can that be done in a secure way? I would have to be backend-driven wouldn't it?

After login you have to save token in local storage then get user data by token

and each time user open your application you have to get user data by token to validate if this token is valid and not expired

you can add AuthGuard service to validate if user have valid token and permission to navigate to requested page

Comment: I checked out AuthGaurd, but that's still client-side is it not? Wouldn't I need to validate serverside eventually? And if so, why use Authguard at all? if I can access localStorage from any point in Typescript, that seems like it would work.

Comment: Yest it's, but anyway you have to do booth validations, Your server side security should not depend on the security of the Javascript, front end validations will minimize back end requests therefore server headache, so you can combine booth validations by checking in auth guard if user has a token then ask server side if it's valid token or not then redirect user to the requested page. ( if user hasn't so no need to ask server and redirect him to login page that's will be more faster than depending on server side in all cases )